# A late '90s early 2000s anime with a amnesiac girl with special power

Tags: dragoon

If anyone could please help I would really appreciate it.

I watched this anime at a friends house, but I forgot to get the title. I think it might have been in the late '90s or early 2000s when this anime was made, but I'm not 100 percent sure.

Anyway, it seems to be set in either middle ages, kind of like *Scrapped Princess* I think. It's about a guy who finds a girl in the snow and he thinks she's dead. When he finds out she is still alive, he takes her back. When she regains consciousness, she has not memory of who she is. I think I remember her having really big boobs. She has some unknown power, and every time she is scared, it gets activated and she becomes topless. They go on a quest to find out who she is, and meet a blonde haired prince (or knight?).

That's all I can really remember and it's just one of those animes I never got to watch past two episodes. I just wanna finish it. If anyone could help, please and thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

### [Dragoon](http://myanimelist.net/anime/3968/Dragoon) (1997)

> In the great Garubado Empire, a lethal weapon is in the process of being manufactured, but is stolen and subsequently lost in battle. Now the Empire is looking for this weapon: a girl that can call forth the "Dragoon" power. She has amnesia and is found by a wandering swordsman in training by who vows to help her find out who she is and why she has such a strange power.

Synopsis of the first episode from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragoon_%28anime%29#Plot):

> In Dragoon, May is the key to unlocking the deadliest weapon, known as the Dragoon. Soon into the film, May is shown in a tube being controlled by two older men. May escapes and finds herself lost in the woods. While sword fighting, a young man named Sedon, hears soldiers and airplanes around where he is practicing his sword techniques. He comes across a search party looking for May, keeping himself hidden behind a row of shrubbery as he follows them. Down the line of hedges, while he isn't looking where he is going Sedon trips. He turns over and realizes what he has stumbled over. He finds May lying naked, unconscious beside him.

[image: Sedon finds May in the snow and takes her back to his cabin]

<sup>**Sorry, no naked picture.**</sup>

> After finding May in the woods, Sedon takes her to his small cabin, in which his father built. They stay there a while, and soon after May awakens. Soon after that, the search party comes across the cabin, and they knock on the door.
>
> Sedon and May escape just in time, but they are leaving tracks in the snow. To hide this, they run down a small nearby stream. The Searchers lose the trail, and Sedon takes May back to his village. After they arrive, Sedon learns of May's Amnesia. She can't remember a thing.

[image: The blonde-hair]

<sup>**Rain Keeves Fearudo, the blonde-haired character.**</sup>

Comment: add synopsis, pic and some information about the episode where question description matches.

Comment: Just saw that in the comment, the OP has already found the title.

Comment: @GaoWeiwei I upvoted anyway, I prefer id requests to have real answers, not answers hidden in the comments of answers.

Answer (score -2):

I would really like to help, there are so many anime in fantasy or medieval setting with a female main character that lost her memories, but i'm not sure any of the ones that come to mind really fit your description.

Came to mind:
Koihime
Pandora Hearts
Tsubasa Chronicle
Kobato
Chobits
Vampire Knight?
Utawarerumono (unlikely)
3x3 Eyes (unlikely)
Kiddy Grade (its in space...)

Comment: It seems a bit too broad. Perhaps narrowing it down to the more likely ones might be a bit easier for the OP. :)

Comment: The OP's description is vague, but not *this* vague. I think we can strike out Tsubasa Chronicle (no topless super attacks), Kobato (not medieval, no topless super attacks), Chobits (robots, no topless super attacks), Utawarerumono (it's a guy, no topless super attacks), 3x3 Eyes (modern day, Chinese setting utterly unlike Scrapped Princess, no topless super attacks) and Kiddy Grade (as you say, it's in space).

Comment: I just googled all of those to check if anything looked familiar unfortunately no luck.  I know its really vague I'm trying to think of something thats not so vague but the only thing that comes to mind is that she has blue hair (not that actually really helps or anything) I figure I at least take my chances and ask I really appreciate you both for taking the time to answer my question :)

Comment: @D24 If you remember something, you should edit your answer to add it. There might be someone for whom this description doesn't ring a bell until they see that the girl had blue hair, and then it all clicks (memory is weird like that). Anyway, sorry I couldn't be more help. I hope you find what you're looking for.

Comment: I looked up major companies that released anime around the time it was released and I found what I was looking for luckily.  My description of the girl's hair color was slightly off the anime is called Dragoon (OAV 1997) thank you MateusSouza and @Torisuda for taking the time to help me!

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Manga, Please keep Identification Request Answer to 1 title/series per answer and also please if you belive a title/series is unlikely to be a match there is no need to even mention it